# How to stop a users profile picture being cached and not displaying correctly php

Tags: php, image, caching

As the user updates his/her profile picture, it's still displaying the previous image for a few minutes. how can I stop this?

Below is the code I tried. I tried

```
  $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'";
  $resultImg = mysqli_query($db, $sqlImg);
  while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {

    echo "<div>";

      if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
        echo "<img   src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg? 
       t='.time()>";
      }
```

Comment: can't see how `$id` is set - but I'll wager that you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `src` attribute too early. Your closing quote needs to be after the `GET` parameter value.

```
echo "<img src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg?t=" .time() . "' >";
```

You also need to close the string and concatenate  the `time()` function so it is processed by the PHP.